# Converting SBT ModuleID with CrossVersion to string

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I convert an sbt `ModuleID` to a string containing a CrossVersion to a string?

In build.sbt (or in a plugin), both the following lines print `com.example:test:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`:

```
println("com.example" %% "test" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
println("com.example" % "test" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

from the first example I would to get `com.example:test_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Actually I would like to be able to extract just `test_2.12` as the name of the module if possible.

How do I manage that?